# PHP query to DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I store information about every single time a page has been loaded. So I have these rows: id, ip, date. Now I want to `SELECT` the 5 most active IP addresses and get the total number of times they have loaded a page. So the result I get should look like this:

1. IP - 193.211.187.1 Visits - 542
2. IP - 192.122.152.1 Visits-451
3. IP - 191.141.100.1 Visits-331

I hope you understand me correctly.

Comment: [counting rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `group by` and `count` to pull the most views by IP.

```
select ip, count(*) as count 
from logs 
group by ip 
order by count desc 
limit 5
```

Simple Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa26a3/1

Comment: Very adequate answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

use this `query` change `table name` according to yours

```
SELECT ip, count( ip) visits
FROM table
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY visits DESC
LIMIT 5
```